# Use a batch file to automatically start 5 separate cmd prompts, where each cmd prompt points to a different directory and starting the php web server

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting, easyphp-webserver

I hope you can help me out with this issue, which I thought would be quite trivial but is turning out to be quite a bugger.
As mentioned in the subject line this is what I want to accomplish:

- Automatically run 5 command prompts, each new command prompt needs to do the following
- Change directories to a specific location
- start the built in php web server

This is the code I currently have for my .bat file:

```
start cmd /k
cd "directory 1"
php -S localhost:8081

start cmd /k
cd "directory 02"
php -S localhost:8082

start cmd /k
cd "directory 03"
php -S localhost:8083

etc...
```

**Update (here are the working commands after some tweaking)**

```
start "Dir1" /d "directory1" cmd /k "php -S localhost:8081"
start "Dir2" /d "directory2" cmd /k "php -S localhost:8082"
start "Dir3" /d "directory3" cmd /k "php -S localhost:8083"
start "Dir4" /d "directory4" cmd /k "php -S localhost:8084"
start "Dir5" /d "directory5" cmd /k "php -S localhost:8085"
start "Dir6" /d "directory6" cmd /k "php -S localhost:8086"
```

Thanks very much.
Cheers,
Tim K

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command has to be on the same line as `cmd /k`, else you start a new window and execute the next line in the original window. `Start` has a `/d` switch to set the working folder for the new process, so you don't need `cd`:

```
start "Dir1" /d "directory 1" cmd /k "php -S localhost:8081"
REM etc.
```

When the folder names and ports are accurate, you can use a `for /L` loop to simplify things:

```
for /l %%i in (1,1,5) do start "Dir %%i" /d "directory %%i" cmd /k "php -S localhost:808%%i"
```

Comment: Thanks very much Stephan however this only seems to start the 1st cmd prompt, and not the others?
I'll update my original question with the commands I now have in the .bat file.

Comment: the first code opens just one prompt, the second one should start five of them (given, the folders `directory %%i` exist  (like you question suggests) - if a folder doesn't exist, no `cmd` is executed and you get an errormessage `invalid directory` instead)

Comment: Thanks once again Stephan, this does seem to be work after a bit of tweaking ;-).

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what did you tweak?

Comment: Please take a look at my updated question for what I needed to tweak.

Comment: Hm. `start cmd /d "dir6" /k "php -S localhost:8086"` starts `cmd /d "dir6" /k "<command>"`, which doesn't make much sense. Sure you don't want `start /d "dir6" cmd /k "<command>"`? Then `for /l %%i in (1,1,6) do start "%%i" /d "dir%%i" cmd /k "php -S localhost:808%%i"` should work.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't actually seem to be working correctly, however it was due to me misunderstanding you, I think I might have it working now though Lol.

Comment: Ok now it's working 100% as expected, please see my updated question. I'll take a look at the for structure you mentioned and see if I can get it working using that rather as it'll definitely be less code, however I'm just concerned about readability for new developers who aren't quite experienced ;-).

Comment: @TimothyKruger the foundation of every programming language has looping. That `FOR` command is pretty basic.  All it is doing it substituting the the value of the iteration into your original code.  It is pretty easy to see what `%%i` is replacing based on your hard coded example.

Comment: @Squashman I totally agree with you that the `FOR` loop structure is very basic, however I'm new to scripting as a whole and my requirements are a bit more complex than what I initially shared, e.g. amongst other things ideally what I would like to do is give each cmd prompt a more descriptive title, i.e. "Google", "Hello Peter", etc. rather than "Dir1", "Dir2" etc. amongst other things which off the top of my head I'm assuming I'll need to create a 2 dimensional array 1st populating it with values and then use that to populate the `FOR` loop making it a bit more complicated ;-).